# sqlite3.IntegrityError в aiogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, sqlite3, aiogram-2.x

Мейн-код:

```
from config import TOKEN, admin_id
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, types, executor
import keyboards
from database import Database
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import CallbackQuery
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN, parse_mode='HTML')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
db = Database('database_1.db')


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def cmd_start(message: types.Message):
    if (not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
        await bot.send_message(admin_id, f'<b> Зашел новый пользователь: @{message.from_user.username}</b>')
    await message.answer(' Привет!\n\n Чтобы получить товар/замену, используй кнопки ниже ',
                         reply_markup=keyboards.main_keyboard)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

код БД:

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def add_user(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE 'user_id' = ?", (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def set_text(self, user_id, text):
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_text') VALUES (?)", (user_id, text,))
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\floydpower\PycharmProjects\support_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\floydpower\PycharmProjects\support_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\floydpower\PycharmProjects\support_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\floydpower\PycharmProjects\support_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\floydpower\PycharmProjects\support_bot\venv\lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\floydpower\PycharmProjects\support_bot\main.py", line 18, in cmd_start
    db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
  File "C:\Users\floydpower\PycharmProjects\support_bot\database.py", line 10, in add_user
    return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)", (user_id,))
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.user_id
```

Суть в чем: когда я нажимаю /start, то все обрабатывается корректно, но когда я прописываю второй раз /start, вылезает ошибка выше. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Это значит, что в таблице такие данные уже есть. Необходимо прописать, если хочешь чтоб было игнорирование то:

```
INSERT or IGNORE
```

Если изменить существующую запись то:

```
INSERT or REPLACE
```

Comment: Теперь мне постоянно приходит, что "Зашел новый пользователь", хотя такого быть не должно

Comment: Проверь выполняется ли у тебя условие проверки новый пользователь или нет. Почему там скобки?

Comment: прикол в том, что в предыдущей программе, которую я писал, все работало корректно, но сейчас фигня происходит

Comment: Я не знаю, что на это ответить, но в данном случае проблема в if